# Recovering a VeraCrypt Volume

Tags: data-recovery, veracrypt

I have a VeraCrypt volume which I mistakenly restored header of the volume using the backup embedded in the volume itself. It says that this process also restores the old password if exist. But I have never changed my password. So I had no problem with password.

Result: I can open and mount the volume with my current password. But when I try to read contents I get: "Sorry, could not display all the contents of “veracrypt8”: Error when getting information for file '/media/veracrypt8/r?.0�': Input/output error"

When I use `ls` command in the volume directory, I get random names like in this screenshot:
[image]

Is there any way to recover my data?

Comment: What tools exactly are you using? i.e. how do you perform the mount and what exact command you used to restore the header?

Comment: You may have a problem with file ownership. Try a rw, set your uid and gid, then 
fmask and dmask to 0077 (or 0007 for group access). Also check the output from dmesg (last few line); it may tell you valuable info.

Comment: @grochmal I am using Veracrypt 1.17 GUI for everything. Never used terminal. From GUI, `volume tools > restore header`

Comment: @Overmind Can you explain or give me a link that explains that process? I have never done it.

Comment: Your OS appear to be either some kind of Ubuntu/Mint or Fedora.  It should have the `cryptsetup` utility (and if it hasn't it should be in the repos).  One useful thing that `cryptsetup` can do it to print the content of the headers, i.e. with `cryptsetup --veracrypt tcryptDump <volume>`.  That will give us useful info.  Then instead of using the GUI, you can mount it with `cryptsetup --verbose --veracrypt tcryptOpen <volume> <name>` (you can assign whatever you like to <name>), that will also give useful info.

Comment: @grochmal Thanks, gonna try that and share the output.

Comment: @Saibot - in short, you must check if you have proper permissions per user and per group. Do you know how to do that on the OS you use the VC volume ? The exact commands may vary depending on your OS, that's why I stated things in a more general manner.

Comment: @Overmind I use Ubuntu. Could you give the commands or a link to a proper tutorial?

Comment: Make sure the volume that has the main file has these permissions: drwxrwsr-x (you can check that with ls -l). If they are not like that, then just use sudo chgrp and sudo chmod (sudo chmod 775) on it and finally add your username to the group you use if it's not in the group already. If the permissions are good and you still get your initial output it means your decryption key is not applied correctly.

Comment: @Overmind It doesn't have required permissions. (drwx only) I tried to change permission but was not possible. Error says its a read-only file system. Now trying to figure out how to disable read-only thing.

Comment: @Overmind Used `sudo mount -o remount,rw '/veracrypt1'` for enabling write, without error, then `sudo chmod 775 veracrypt` without error, but still `ls -l` gives drwx.

Comment: If it's drwx then certainly the decryption key is incorrect. You should try to re-restore maybe VC will use the correct key, or find a way to manually set the used key.